# Two stage mixed models for repeated measures as predictors of binary outcomes

Tags: mixed-models

I wish to explore repeated measures of biomarkers as predictors of binary outcomes, for example changes in CRP or BMI according to death during years of follow-up.
I have come across a couple of papers (for example https://bmcpediatr.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s12887-019-1830-y) that have utilized two stage mixed models in this regard; however I do not know how to use (or make any) R syntax to perform the analyses.

Does anybody have an idea on how to set the syntax up, or even better: know about a useful R package?

Comment: AFAIK that "two stage mixed model" isn't a widely used term, the paper you cited lists the packages they used - "Statistical analysis was performed using R software, version 3.3.2. The package of nlme was used for two stage mixed effects analysis. Mclust package was the optimal model for parameterized Gaussian mixture clustering by hierarchical clustering." As far as setting it up - you can, with data, show us where you are stuck, and we can probably help.

Comment: I am not a statistician, but a doctor doing clinical work. I have slight experience with R, but I was not able to understand any of the set-up the authors described in the paper, despite the packages cited. I was hpoing for some sort of 'recipe' on a syntax or if anybody knows about a paper describing the methodology in practical terms.

Comment: can you post your data, or data that are similar?